# How to pass a numeric id to a page template?

Tags: page-template, child-theme, theme-twenty-thirteen, social-connect

I am using a Wordpress installation with [Wordpress Social Login](http://miled.github.io/wordpress-social-login/) as a "canvas" for an HTML5-based board game.

In the file `/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/front-page.php` I get the numeric `ID` of the viewing user (returned by [wp_get_current_user() method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)) and then her or his Facebook data (id, first name, last name, gender) from the `$wpdb->prefix . 'wslusersprofiles'` table - and can display the game and score for that user at the front page of my website.

**My question please:** underneath the game board I would like to show a list of *other* players (maybe a "top 10" or maybe a list of *all* players with the help of [DataTables jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net)).

I would like to have a link like `/player/12345` or `/player-12345` for each player in the list - so that it is possible to click on it and then display the first name and score for that player.

I keep reading [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) and looking at [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://wphierarchy.com) and just don't understand - what should be the path of my user profile file (something like `/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/page-templates/player.php`?) and especially how to pass the numeric id part (the `12345` in the above example) to that file?

**UPDATE:**

I have added [functions.php and page-templates/page-player.php](https://github.com/afarber/wp-newbie/tree/master/twentythirteen-child) as suggested by Jevuska in his very detailed answer.

Unfortunately, I get 404 error, when trying to open `/player-1` (that would be me as admin) or `/player-12345` - even though I flush rewrite rules unconditionally in `wp_loaded` hook.

I am using PHP 5.3 on CentOS 6.7 Linux

Comment: I test your child theme and thats work. I use PHP 7. Have you create new page with slug `player` from admin?

Comment: It just for additional information, if you use [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), WP say: _Note that the previous method was to import the parent theme stylesheet using @import: this is no longer best practice._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regard to WordPress [post paged](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged), I would use `/player-12345` or other structure as url specific page rather than `/player/12345`.

#### How to create new url structure for page

Creating additional url structure, you need [`WP_Rewrite`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), there are a couple of filters that you can fire with your function. For **Page**, you can filter [`page_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_rewrite_rules). See example code on documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples. Pay attention for notes in those documentation.

This is sample code related with your url structure `/player-12345`. Make sure your page slug is `player`. Add this code in theme file `functions.php` or inside your plugin.

```
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules()
{
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
    
    if ( ! isset( $rules['(player)-(\d*)$'] ) )
    {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule page slug with number
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(player)-(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&player_id=$matches[2]';
    
    return $newrules + $rules; //combine all page rules
}

// Adding the player_id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push( $vars, 'player_id' );
    return $vars;
}
```

Now you have url structure page with user id `/player-12345`, create page link in your front-page base on your database. You can use [`get_page_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link) and combine with your list user id.

#### Create page or custom page

Then how to display our user data in front-end ?

[Create new page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Pages) ( Player with slug `player` from admin ), it will use default `page.php` template, you can use just it. But if you need in different layout, creating new file theme `page-{slug}.php` ( without template name ) is my prefered method, in your case `page-player.php`.

Create duplicate code from the `page.php`, and customize as necessary. You don't have to create custom `wp_query` with loop inside. Just use normal loop `wp_query` as is.

Since we have additional query parameter for page is `player_id` with user ID value, with `get_query_var( 'player_id' )` it make easy to retrieve user data.

This is simple code to display user data, I just use user query, you can implement on your way with data from your new table. Filtering [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) with function to retrieve user data and keep the original page content ( you can overwrite too ). Add in `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
/**
 * Filter page content
 * by filter the_content
 * Use condition statement is_page( slug ) with get_query_var( 'player_id' )
 * 
 * @param  string $content Oringinal text
 * @return string New Content with or without original text
 */
function my_the_content_filter( $content )
{
    if ( is_page( 'player' ) && ! empty( get_query_var( 'player_id' ) ) )
    {
        $player_id = intval( get_query_var( 'player_id' ) );

        /**
         * Add user info only ( overwrite page content )
           $content = _my_function_player_info( $player_id );
         */

        /**
         * Include your page content and additional content of user info
         */
        $content .= _my_function_player_info( $player_id );
    }
    return $content;
}

/**
 * Set your user data, html, table, etc
 * @see param https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/
 * @param  integer $player_id User ID
 * @return string User data front-end
 */
function _my_function_player_info( $player_id )
{
    ob_start();
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', intval( $player_id ) );
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php _e( 'Name', 'text_domain' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
}
```

Another filter such as `loop_start` or `loop_end` to display user data before or after content loop, and use `echo` in output, or implement your function direct into custom page. Just abuse this code as your need.

Comment: You in child, twentythirteen don't have page-templates, just add page-player.php the same path with functions.php.

Comment: I have moved `page-player.php` into `/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child` dir and unfortunately still get 404 error, even after restarting Apache. Do I need some special PHP-comment in my new page template file?

Comment: Have you create new page with slug `player` from admin?

Comment: How to do that please? As admin I go to `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page` and then? How to make it "player" page?

Comment: Create title "Player" and you will see WP create page permalink with slug 'player' automatically, then publish.