# How to create and populate with few links a menu in child theme functions.php?

Tags: theme-development, menus, child-theme, theme-twenty-thirteen

The official *Twenty Thirteen* theme defines just a single menu in the [/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/header.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/header.php) file:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'primary', 
    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 
    'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

In the child theme of my website I am trying to populate that menu *programmatically* in the [/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/functions.php](https://github.com/afarber/wp-newbie/blob/master/twentythirteen-child/functions.php) file, because:

1. It makes reinstalling the website easier (less manual steps).
2. The last menu item should point to [/player-ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222638/how-to-pass-a-numeric-id-to-a-page-template) link.

So I have tried to add the code:

```
function my_register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
         )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_register_menus' );
```

but that does not change anything in the appearance of the website.

Also I have (re)read [Navigation Menus](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/navigation-menus/) in Theme Handbook (incl. API links) and still don't understand, how to pass an array of links to the menu.

I probably should call [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) with some array of objects, but can not find the desciption of such objects.

At the end I would like to add 4 links to the menu:

1. "Play game" - `/`
2. "Android" - `/android`
3. "iOS" - `/ios`
4. "Your profile" - `/player-ID` (will take `ID` from [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.
Since you already have the menu-id all you need [is](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_nav_menu_item/):

```
$menu_item_defaults = array(
                    'menu-item-db-id' => $menu_item_db_id,
                    'menu-item-object-id' => 0,
                    'menu-item-object' => '',
                    'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
                    'menu-item-position' => 1,
                    'menu-item-title' => 'Play Game',
                    'menu-item-url' => '',//not sure is a blank is ok here
                    'menu-item-description' => '',
                    'menu-item-attr-title' => '',
                    'menu-item-target' => '',
                    'menu-item-classes' => '',
                    'menu-item-xfn' => '',
                    'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
                );

wp_update_nav_menu_item('primary-menu', 0, $menu_item_defaults);
```

However, it you're trying to speed deployment of a site with known content try it this way. You can create the page and add it to the menu all on the fly.

In my case I'm creating a custom menu first but you can use this to get the id of any menu.

```
$menu_exists = wp_get_nav_menu_object( 'Public Menu' );
if ( $menu_exists === false ) {
    $var_pub_menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'Public Menu' );
} else {
    $var_pub_menu_id = $menu_exists->term_id;
}
```

Then I create my page and add it to the menu:

```
$default_fgpsn_page = array(
    'post_title'    => $fgpsn_default_pages[$j],//any page title. I'm working in a loop here
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_content'   => 'Property Browse Short Code',//this can even be a shortcode
    'post_author'   => 1
    );

   $default_fgpsn_page_id = wp_insert_post( $default_fgpsn_page );

            $menu_item_defaults = array(
                //'menu-item-db-id' => $menu_item_db_id,
                //'menu-item-object-id' => 0,
                //'menu-item-object' => '',
                'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
                'menu-item-position' => 1,
                'menu-item-title' => $fgpsn_default_pages[$j],
                'menu-item-url' => get_page_link( $default_fgpsn_page_id ),
                'menu-item-description' => 'public properties listing',
                'menu-item-attr-title' => '',
                'menu-item-target' => '',
                'menu-item-classes' => '',
                'menu-item-xfn' => '',
                'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
            );

            wp_update_nav_menu_item($var_pub_menu_id, 0, $menu_item_defaults);
```